# Como subir um arquivo no servidor - Asp .net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp, iis

Boa tarde, fiz um pequeno projeto em asp .net cujo o único objetivo é selecionar um arquivo no meu computador e salva-lo no servidor. O problema é que não estou conseguindo realizar este procedimento após publicar o projeto no IIS.
O código que estou utilizando é o seguinte:

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult SalvarArquivo(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if(file == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Upload"); ;
        }

        try
        {
            if(file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var nomeArquivo = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                string[] split = nomeArquivo.Split('.');

                if(split[1] == "xlsx")
                {
                    //var caminho = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), "teste.xlsx");

                    string path = string.Format(@"c:\inetpub\ftproot\minhapasta\{0}", "teste.xlsx");

                    file.SaveAs(path);

                    ViewBag.Mensagem = "Arquivo enviado e salvo com sucesso no servidor.";

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Mensagem = "O Arquivo enviado não é válido, selecione um arquivo com extensão 'xlsx'!";

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ViewBag.Mensagem = string.Format("Não foi possível enviar o arquivo: {0}", e.Message);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

    }
```

View:

```
<h2>SalvarArquivo</h2>


<h1>AlliBus - Carga de Planilha </h1>
<hr />
<div>
<form action="/Upload/SalvarArquivo" method="post" enctype="multipart/form- 
 data">
    <label for="file">Nome do Arquivo :</label>
    <br />
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />
    <p>
        @ViewBag.Mensagem
</form>
</div>
```

Dentro do servidor, o caminho onde quero salvar o arquivo é em: "c:\inetpub\ftproot\minhapasta\". Como posso fazer para salvar meu arquivo neste local? Desde já agradeço a quem puder ajudar. Atenciosamente.

Comment: Porque??? Como está configurado a sua aplicação é dentro de `ftproot`??? essa pasta você tem autorização para gravar arquivos??? eu não estou conseguindo entender como está a sua aplicação e porque desse caminho absoluto para gravar esse arquivo, poderia explicar??? Qual ou quais erros acontecem ou problemas?

Comment: Olá Virgilio, obrigado por responder. Bem, minha aplicação esta no caminho "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\minhaaplicacao" e eu quero gravar o arquivo em "c:\inetpub\ftproot\minhapasta\". Até onde eu verifiquei tenho autorização para fazer gravações nesta pasta. Com relação a erros, simplesmente não aparece nenhum, quando rodo a aplicação localmente, ele grava o arquivo no caminho especificado, porem quando faço a publicação e peço para salvar na pasta informada ele não salva.

Comment: estranho não aparecer erro, porque tem que ter alguma informação é um problema que sem verificar junto ao servidor e serviço fica complicado dizer qualquer coisa.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, entendi, mas pelo menos em teoria o código está certo? no sentido de acessar uma outra pasta dentro do servidor? Vou realizar mais alguns testes, para ver se consigo obter alguma mensagem de erro. Obrigado novamente.

Comment: depende da permissão e aonde o Servidor pode chegar, não é normal o que você está fazendo ...

Comment: Edite manualmente o arquivo `Web.Config` publicado servidor, acrescentando a propriedade `debug="true"` na tag `compilation`. Isso vai permitir mostrar o erro ao tentar salvar novamente o arquivo. Tente ae e veja o erro...